# How do i publish a vs code extension with space

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been working on a vs code extension and want to publish it with spaces in the name. I saw other extensions have them, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: The `displayName` in your package.json can have spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mark said, the `displayName` in the `package.json` can have spaces. I never thought it would be this simple.